# Setting An Attribute On a has_many_through Join Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, model, has-many-through

I have a `has_many_through` relationship between a `Contributor` and a `Resource` through a `Contributorship`. What makes it unusual is that when I set up the association I need to set a `contribution_type` for the :

```
model Contributor

  has_many contributorships
  has_many contributors, through: contributorships

end

model Resource

  has_many contributorships
  has_many resources, through: contributorships

end

model Contributorships

  attr_accessible :contribution_type, :contributor, :archive_resource

  belongs_to resources
  belongs_to contributors

end
```

Setting up an association involves either:

```
c = Contributor.create!()
r = Resource.create!()
c.contributorships.create!(resource:r,  contribution_type: :author)
```

Or (If I don't want to save upfront):

```
c = Contributor.new()
r = Resource.new()
cs = Contributorship.new(contributor:c, resource:r,  contribution_type: :author)
c.save!
r.save!
cs.save!
```

If I didn't need to set the `contribution_type` atttribute on the `Contributorship` join Model I could do:

```
c.resources << r
```

**So is there a more elgant way of doing this *and* setting the attribute at the same time?**

Comment: What is the type? A random string or a set of predefined values from an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`build`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-build) to automatically set associations between instantiated objects.

```
contributor = Contributor.new
contributor.contributorships.build(:contribution_type => :author)
contributor.resources.build
contributor.save!
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value of contributor_type is dependent on values from one of the other models I'd be inclined to just write a before_validation callback to set the correct corresponding value every time a Contributorships was created. i.e.

```
model Contributorships

  attr_accessible :contribution_type, :contributor, :archive_resource

  belongs_to resources
  belongs_to contributors

  before_validation :set_contributor_type

  def set_contributor_type
     if self.new_record?
        # Whatever code you need to determine the type value
        self.contributor_type = value
     end
  end

end
```

If instead this is a user defined value then you'll need to use the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`in which ever model defines your `contributor_type` and then in the form use `fields_for` to allow the user to set the value when creating the record. This is covered very comprehensively and in good detail in the following railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2?view=asciicast

**I.e:**

```
<%= form_for(contributor) do |f| %>
   # Whatever fields you want to save for the contributor
   <% contributorship = f.object.contributorships.build %>
   <%= f.fields_for(:contributorships, contributorship) do |new_contributorship| %>
         # Whatever fields you want to save for the contributorship
         <% resource = new_contributorship.object.resources.build %>
         <%= f.fields_for(:resources, resource) do |new_resource| %>
                # Whatever fields you want to save for the resource
         <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Nice thinking, but unfortunately it isn't dependent on a model value.

Comment: So, is it set by the user (i.e. via a drop down on a form or something?)

Comment: Yep. Each contributor can have a `contributor_type` of either `author` or `editor`.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be much more complex than this. I'm familiar with using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but that doesn't help with the problem which is the need to create, or update the attribute on the join model. If I wanted to set an attribute on the model at the other end of the association this would be useful. Also there is an updated version of that Railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?autoplay=true

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it properly. I met using the `accepts_nested_attribues_for` both for your join model and child. See my updated answer.